# Using a javascript variable in server side call MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, powerbi-embedded

I'm currently using power BI embedded to embed reports in a web app and I want to create functionality to switch between reports in a group using a drop down box. I have managed to populate the drop down box with the appropriate data but am now struggling to actually switch between reports. I can successfully do it if i hard code the number into the server side call but obviously this is not scalable and isnt the solution. Below is my cshtml I need a way for the "@Model" calls in reportSelector.onchange to be able to see the selected variable.

```
@model TaskWebApp.Models.EmbedConfig[]

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model[0].ErrorMessage))
{
    <div id="errorWrapper">
        <h2>
            Error
        </h2>
        @Model[0].ErrorMessage
    </div>

    return;
}

<div>
    <p>Select report</p>
    <select id="reportSelector"></select>
</div>
<div id="reportContainer"></div>

<script>
    // Read embed application token from Model
    var accessToken = "@Model[0].EmbedToken.Token";

    // Read embed URL from Model
    var embedUrl = "@Html.Raw(Model[0].EmbedUrl)";

    // Read report Id from Model
    var embedReportId = "@Model[0].Id";

    // Get models. models contains enums that can be used.
    var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

    // Embed configuration used to describe the what and how to embed.
    // This object is used when calling powerbi.embed.
    // This also includes settings and options such as filters.
    // You can find more information at https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details.
    var config = {
        type: 'report',
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
        accessToken: accessToken,
        embedUrl: embedUrl,
        id: embedReportId,
        permissions: models.Permissions.All,
        settings: {
            filterPaneEnabled: true,
            navContentPaneEnabled: true
        }
    };
    // Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
    var reportContainer = $('#reportContainer')[0];

    // Embed the report and display it within the div container.
    var report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);

    var reportSelector = $('#reportSelector')[0];
    var optionString = "@Html.Action("PopulateDropdown", "Embed", Model[0].Reports)";
    reportSelector.onchange = function () { 
        var selected = this.selectedIndex;
        var accessToken = "@Model[selected].EmbedToken.Token";

        // Read embed URL from Model
        embedUrl = "@Html.Raw(Model[selected].EmbedUrl)";

        // Read report Id from Model
        embedReportId = "@Model[selected].Id";

        // Get models. models contains enums that can be used.
        models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

        // Embed configuration used to describe the what and how to embed.
        // This object is used when calling powerbi.embed.
        // This also includes settings and options such as filters.
        // You can find more information at https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details.
        config = {
            type: 'report',
            tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
            accessToken: accessToken,
            embedUrl: embedUrl,
            id: embedReportId,
            permissions: models.Permissions.All,
            settings: {
                filterPaneEnabled: true,
                navContentPaneEnabled: true
            }
        };
        var report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);
    }
    reportSelector.innerHTML = optionString;
</script>
```

Let me know if it is necessary to see the model or the controller. Any help is appreciated as I'm somewhat new to MVC and am struggling with not being able to use variables in the way i want.

Edit: function that creates dropdown:

```
public string PopulateDropdown(ODataResponseListReport reports)
        {
            foreach (Claim claim in ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims)
            {
                if (claim.Type == "extension_GroupID")
                {
                    GroupId = claim.Value;
                }
            }
            string retVal = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < reports.Value.Count; i++)
            {
                retVal += "<option>" + reports.Value.ElementAtOrDefault(i).Name + "</option>";
            }
            return retVal;
        }
```

Comment: What dropdownlist? And `@Model` is razor code - its parsed on the server before its sent to the view. Code such as `var accessToken = "@Model[selected].EmbedToken.Token";` does not work because `selected` is a javascript variable which does not exist at that point.

Comment: ive added the function that creates the dropdown which is in the controller

Comment: yes ive come across the fact that its razor but a shove in the right direction of how i can push this variable through into a controller method or something along those lines would be great

Comment: That is the strangest way I have ever seen to attempt to create a dropdown. You can always serialize your model to a javascript variable - e.g. `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` and then access it with your indexer - `var accessToken = "model[selected].EmbedToken.Token";`

Comment: serializing worked a treat. Don't know if you wanted to create an answer i could accept for this solution. I'm sure its quite hackish that was born of a similar issue of not quite understanding scope issues presented working with MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Model` is razor code and is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. Using `var accessToken = "@Model[selected].EmbedToken.Token";` etc throws an error because `selected` is a javascript variable which does not exist at that point - its not in scope.

You can assign your model to a javascript array using

```
var model = var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

and then access it using your indexer

```
var accessToken = model[selected].EmbedToken.Token;
```